# Generate survival data with functional data using R

Tags: r, survival, simulation, proportional-hazards, functional-data-analysis

I am reading this article [here](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-applied-statistics/volume-11/issue-3/Dynamic-prediction-of-disease-progression-for-leukemia-patients-by-functional/10.1214/17-AOAS1050.full) and trying to regenerate their simulation study. Here is this scenario here, among others, but if I can figure out one, the rest follow. That is,

**Simulation set-up**

we assume the hazard function of subject $i$ is
\begin{equation}
h_i(t|Z_i(t)) = h_0(t) \exp(\alpha Z_i(t)),
\end{equation}
where $h_0(t) = \lambda t^{\lambda-1} \exp(\eta)$, a Weibull baseline hazard function with $\lambda = 2$, $\eta = -5$, and the association parameter $\alpha = 0.5$.

Consider the linear model.

$$
Z_i(t) = a + bt + b_{i1} + b_{i2}t,
$$

The linear longitudinal trajectory is described with $a = 1$, $b = -2$. Trajectories considered above use random effect terms $b_i = (b_{i1}, b_{i2}) \sim \mathcal{N}(0,D))$, with $D = \begin{pmatrix} 0.4 & 0.1 \\ 0.1 & 0.2 \end{pmatrix}$. For simplicity, we generate longitudinal data on irregular time points $t = 0$ and $t = j + \epsilon_{ij}$, $j = 1, 2, \ldots, 10$ and $\epsilon_{ij} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, .1^{2})$ independent across all $i$ and $j$. We simulated the censoring times from a uniform distribution in $(0, t_{\text{max}})$, with $t_{\text{max}}$ set to result in about 25% censoring.

**My questions**

1. Eventually, my goal is to generate survival time (the follow-up time) and status for each subject. So, should I integrate \begin{equation}
   h_i(t|Z_i(t)) = h_0(t) \exp(\alpha Z_i(t)),
   \end{equation} from $0$ to $t$ to obtain the cumulative hazard $H(t)$ then obtain $S(t)=\exp(-H(t))$ and the inverse of $S(t)$, $t=S^{-1}(u)$. You then generate $U\sim\mathrm{Uniform\left(0,1\right)}$, substituting $U$ for $S\left(t\right)$ and to simulate $t$, the follow up time.
2. Given what I have said in part (1) is correct, here I am trying to do it numerically, and obviously not working since I have negative time and am also not sure how I would be using my t as described in the simulation. It would be possible to do it analytically and work through steps to obtain the survival time.

Comment: I provided an answer that deals with a statistical aspect of the question, but the coding-specific parts are off-topic on this site. For coding problems per se, Stack Overflow is a better site. [This search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=simulat*+survival) provides a few hundred related questions on this site that might include further hints. The [`simsurv` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=simsurv) probably can do this work for you.

Comment: @EdM Thank you for mentioning this package, I am aware of it but I rather understand and see what I am coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coding-specific part of this question is off-topic on this site, but there is one principle of survival analysis that you should consider implementing.

Simulating event times typically starts as you suggest, sampling from a uniform distribution over (0,1) and then finding the time corresponding to that survival fraction. The way you have this structured makes sense if you want to sample multiple event times from a distribution. In this scenario, however, you only want to take a single event-time sample from each of the randomly generated hazard functions.

Take advantage of the following relationship between $S(t)$ and the cumulative hazard $H(t)$:

$$H(t)=- \log S(t)$$

After you have your sample of the survival fraction from the uniform distribution, start to integrate your (necessarily non-negative) hazard function $h(t)$ from $t=0$ until you reach the value of $H$ corresponding to that survival fraction. Record the upper limit of integration at which that occurs as the event time. If you instead get to some maximum observation time without reaching that value of $H$, record a right-censored observation at that maximum time.

As an example, sample a survival probability and find the corresponding cumulative hazard:

```
set.seed(2)
(cumHazTarget <- -log(runif(1)))
## [1] 1.688036
```

Define your hazard function, with random effects of 0 in this instance:

```
hazF <- function(t) 2*t*exp(-5)*exp(0.5*(1+2*t))
```

Now find the value of $t$ that gives an integrated (i.e., cumulative) hazard equal to the above target. [This page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28328660/5044791) shows a simple way to find the upper limit of integration that gives a desired target for a definite integral. More-or-less copying that here (with a restriction of the lower limit of integration to 0) and applying it to this instance:

```
findprob <- function(f, interval, target) {
    optimize(function(x) {
        abs(integrate(f, 0, x)$value-target)
    }, interval)$minimum
}
findprob(hazF, interval=c(0,10),cumHazTarget)
## [1] 3.429483
```

That gives the time at which the cumulative hazard equals that corresponding to your sampled survival probability. (I suspect that there is a more efficient way to do this that takes advantage of the non-negativity of the hazard function, but this illustrates the principle.)

Set the top limit of `interval` to a value somewhat above your maximum observation time and treat times greater than the maximum observation time as right censored. For example, if your maximum observation time is 3, in this instance the function returns a time value slightly above 3, which you could then right censor at 3:

```
findprob(hazF, interval=c(0,3.1),cumHazTarget)
## [1] 3.099922
```

Comment: The coding part is not an issue to me. Would you please elaborate a bit more on your answer here. Thank you!

Comment: @ADAM I added an example.

Comment: Thank you so much for the update. One last question here, where would I be using this piece of information "We simulated the censoring times from a uniform distribution in $(0,t_{max)), with  $_{}$ set to result in about 25% censoring

Comment: @ADAM as in [my answer to your related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/616727/28500), use that after you've estimated all the event times. It's a trial-and-error process. Start with all events greater than your maximum observation time as censored. Sample uniformly distributed individual censoring times at a value of $t_{max}$. Censor event times greater than the corresponding $t_{max}$. Try different values of $t_{max}$  to get to a _total_ of about 25% of event times censored. Obviously, your maximum observation time needs to be greater than 75% of event times for that to work.

Comment: Is it something like this, but I do not see where would I be using maximum observation time  `times <- findprob(hazF, interval=c(0,10),cumHazTarget) # vector of times (n)`
   `censor_times <- runif(n, min = 0, max = max)`
 `ztime <- pmin(times, censor_times)`
  `event <- as.integer(times <censor_times)`

Comment: @ADAM the paper you cite involves a maximum observation/follow-up time $U$. All simulated event times greater than $U$ thus must be right-censored at $U$. Do that censoring _before_ you do the further censoring with `runif(n,min=0,max=tmax)`. That might further censor some such cases at times even earlier than $U$. Play with `tmax` to get the desired total fraction of censored observations. Also, for efficiency in implementation you will want to `Vectorize()` the `findprob()` function.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. I have updated my code here. My question is not a coding question; it is definitely not the most efficient code at all; I can work on improving that once I have the correct answer. You see that before doing any further censoring using `runif(n,min=0,max=tmax)`, I have a censoring rate over 96%. So, I was wondering what am I doing wrong that made it this way. I would greatly appicaitected if you would point that out or direct me through it. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @ADAM try a much much larger value of `tmax`than the maximum observation time. You need to play with different values of `tmax` to find one that works.

Comment: would you please take a look at this question, please : https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/638069/two-component-cox-proportional-hazards-model-simulation